# Size difference between Flex 3 and Flex 4 SWF's

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

SWF size for a flex mxml I'm working on:

Flex 3:  355896

Flex 4  54988

How can I decrease the size of the Flex 3 version

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found this here:
http://adriansule.com/blog/tag/reduce-flex-size/
I guess Flex 4 does this automatically now.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer to help out others who are having the same issue when you're able to.